# disable two-finger scrolling

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, high-sierra, trackpad

Can I set up a keyboard shortcut to toggle two-finger scrolling on my trackpad?

In some situations, like when watching videos on youtube, VLC, or playing video games, accidental trackpad scrolling is a real pain.

I'd like to disable scrolling in these situations.

Comment: Have you gone to System Preferences/Trackpad?

Comment: @jmh yeah of course, there's no options there to turn it off. If there were I could map some keyboard shortcut to an AppleScript to select them, but Apple doesn't seem to provide any options to disable trackpad scrolling in the GUI at least.